# Email address resolution

Tags: email, resolution

Hi : What is the minimilistic way to setup multiple emails (for domains I own) to all resolve to the same central email address ?

I know it is easy to use email-forwarding with typical domain server utilities found on sites such as godaddy... But I'd rather not simply automate forwarding, because I don't want my email stored on multiple servers for this particular project, due to legal issues related to data and attachment privacy for a client.

Answer (score 1):

You have to point the MX entries for all the domains to your mail server and then configure it to map all domains to the same account(s). How this is done depends on your mail server of choice, which you don't name.

Answer (score 1):

Go Daddy Forwarding Accounts are email accounts that have no boxes attached to them but just send the mail onto another address(s) you the mail to actually be received at.  The emails are not stored in a box for the address originally sent to.  For example, you might want the address support@coolexample.com to forward messages to you@anothercoolexample.com.  Emails sent to support@coolexample.com would be received by you@anothercoolexample.com and no messages would be in a box for support@coolexample.com.